# Get data from a field using query in Computed field and use it as an array

Tags: entities, theming

I have a content type wherein the user will add holidays.

It has Holiday Date field(field_holiday_date).

How can I get the dates in that column using query and use it as an array in Computed field?

[image]

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any value of node or something else in jquery like

```
$node_id = 5;
$node = node_load($node_id);
$settings = array(
    'title' => $node->title,
    'custom-data' => 'ABC',
);
drupal_add_js(array('mymodule' => $settings), 'setting');
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'mymodule') . '/js/mymodule.js', 'file');
```

And get that value in jquery like (you have to put this code in mymodule.js)

```
(function($) {
        Drupal.behaviors.mymodule = {
            attach: function(context, settings) {            
                var title = Drupal.settings.mymodule.title;
                console.log(title); // or perform some operation as you prefer
                var custom_data = Drupal.settings.mymodule.custom-data;
                console.log(custom_data );
            }
        };
    }(jQuery));
```